# getServletContext().getRealPath("") returning null In WebLogic

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, weblogic12c

When the below line it got executed

```
String realPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("");
String imagePath = realPath/images/product/abc.jpeg;
System.out.println("ImagePath-> " + imagePath)
```

When I trying to print the sys out line, I can see the realPath returning null in weblogic as `null/images/product/abc.jpeg`

When I google for the solution. There are two solution I found:-
1.By manually I can go to Weblogic Console -> Domains -> Web Application -> Check the archived real path
(which I dont want to do)
2.I can add the below entry into weblogic.xml manually

```
   <container-descriptor>
        <show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>
    </container-descriptor>
```

which I added in `weblogic.xml` and tried to redeploy but still realPath is returning null after adding in xml files.

As soon as I am trying the first approach by changing the settings in console , then I can see realPath is returning proper path.But which I don't wan't that user should do any changes.

Is any other alternate way apart from the above two for weblogic or may be I am missing something.

Comment: Try getRealPath("/images/product/abc.jpeg").

Comment: @EJP-- thank you..i vl give a try

Comment: not to hijack, but is this a general solution?  will this work on glassfish?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me on WLS12.1.3 using your second option. 
Both methods are documented by Oracle:
**Invoking ServletContext.getRealPath() in archived web applications throws NullPointerException (Doc ID 858783.1)**

Based on that note, I am afraid there is no 3rd option.